# Is there a notification for the new Find Maggie mini game?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

I played this minigame once as part of a quest and apparently I have to wait 16 hours to play it again. How do I know when it is ready? I want to play it as much as possible so I can earn Donuts from it.

Comment: not that i'm aware. the game doesn't tell you if you have any ready horse bets, car bets, scratch cards, shuttle launches or maggie searches. you just have to do it every 16 hrs. i do it every monring, so i know that in 3 days, i get 3 donuts

Comment: You get notifications for scratch bets and horse bets and they also have an icon....

Comment: figures. i turned off my notifications. but when i did have them on, i never got anything for those games. ah well. i'm quite happy with doing the maggie game everyday, as i will play at 6am, which would make the next playtime 10pm. but doing it everyday works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mini-game, similar to the horse bets and scratch cards, will have an image over the location (in this case, a picture of Maggie's head over the daycare) so that you can know when it is available. However, if you have assigned Maggie a task, you won't actually be able to play the mini game with her until she is free from that task.